# Dynamically change image characteristics (width,height ... etc)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

This link is an example of a site that I want to create like it:

> domainName/Content/Upload/Images/bird.jpg?anchor=middlecenter&crop=auto&scale=both&w=200&h=294

which crops the image or increases or decreases its height and width based on the input parameters .I want to know how I can implement it in ASP.NET CORE 7

Comment: You just want to pass this data "anchor=middlecenter&crop=auto&scale=both&w=200&h=294"? in the query string? Right?

Comment: Yes, and based on these parameters, it changes the image and returns it to me in a Get request

Answer (score 2):

You need to use some third-party library to achieve your scenario in asp.net core. Here is a simply demo achieved by `SixLabors.ImageSharp`. Hope it can give you some help.

```
[HttpPost("upload")]
        public IActionResult Upload(IFormFile imageFile, [FromQuery] int width, [FromQuery] int height)
        {

            string path = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Test";

            using (Image image = Image.Load(imageFile.OpenReadStream()))
            {
                image.Mutate(ctx => ctx.Resize(new ResizeOptions
                {
                    Mode = ResizeMode.Crop,
                    Size = new Size(width, height)
                }));

                path = Path.Combine(path, "New.png");

                using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(path))
                {
                    image.Save(fs, new PngEncoder());                  
                }
            }

            return Ok();
            
        }
```

Here is an image in my folder like:

[image]

Then I upload it with url :

```
xxxxxxx/xxxx/upload?width=800&height=500
```

It will save the uploaded image with the given size

[image]

There are many parameters can edit the upload image in this library, You can refer to it's [github library](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp) to learn more.

**================Update===================**

```
[HttpPost("upload/{filename}")]
        public IActionResult Upload(string filename, [FromQuery] int width, [FromQuery] int height)
        {

            string path = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Test";
            path = Path.Combine(path, filename);

            using (Image image = Image.Load(path))
            {
                image.Mutate(ctx => ctx.Resize(new ResizeOptions
                {
                    Mode = ResizeMode.Crop,
                    Size = new Size(width, height)
                }));

                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    image.SaveAsPng(memoryStream);

                    // Return the image as a File Content Result
                    return File(memoryStream.ToArray(), "image/png");
                }
            }  
        }
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, but You have written for me the size change at the time of uploading. While I want a note, when a request is given to download a photo. Its size should be passed as a query string, then the photo should be downloaded. Any size requested by the user

Comment: @jack , Check the code I updated, now it will return the image with given size, It is what you want.

Comment: I think you still don't understand what I mean. Your code is for file upload. I have no problem with the upload. Imagine there is a file on the server, I want to be able to change its size and receive it when the user requests it.

Comment: Have you checked the answer i  updated? When i send request with given size, The server will return the image with given sized,

Comment: I need a `get` method instead of `post` that . Don't just change the size, but also cover the parameters (crop,scale ,...) that I included in my question

Answer (score 0):

You can add all the data in the Model and send the data.

```
public class ImageSizeModel
{
    public string Anchor { get; set; }
    public string Crop { get; set; }
    public string Scale { get; set; }
    public int W { get; set; }
    public int H { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the controller you can add [FromBody] attribute and get all the data as below.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ImageSizeController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetResizedImage([FromBody] ImageSizeModel imageSizeModel)
    {
        //Process Your Image here and Return it.
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Swagger Screen Shot:
[image: Sending the data]

Here is how its received in the controller.

[image: Controller Screen Shot]